# What is the data type used by set in python internally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Interviewer asked me that what is the data type used by set internally in python and what is the time complexity of inserting value in set.

I tried to search on google but I am not getting any specific answer in google search.

Also, I tried to find the set class to check data type used by set in python but not able to find.

Comment: A hash table, each entry in the table is a linked list, in order to allow collisions. Time complexity of O(log(n)) for insertion, I believe.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb: hash tables do not feature O(log(n)) behavior. You must confuse with balanced search trees.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yeah, I was thinking of retrieval (search), not insertion.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb: no operation takes O(log(n)).

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The number of "direct" entries i a hash table is typically much smaller than the total number of different values within the range being mapped (hashed). Hence, each entry maps to a list of values. Finding the mapped value within that list will subsequently take O(log(n)), where n is the length of that list. And in a worst case scenario, all of the values mapped so far have ended on the same list, meaning that the overall search running time is O(log(n)).

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb: the search time is O(1).

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Don't be arrogant and just throw statements in the air. If you know how the internals of general-purpose hashing (allowing any size of input range) work to allow something like that, then please bother to explain! Since the size of the hash table cannot be infinite, the hashing needs to handle possible collisions. These collisions are handled by mapping lists instead of single values. Searching a list depends on the length of that list.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb: Gonnet & Baeza-Yates, pp.43 ff.

Comment: Hi @SaurabhVerma, welcome to StackOverflow. I believe your question has been answered. If that is the case, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set` as well as `dict` use `hash table` as internal data type. As described in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

"A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects"

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can you please provide some reference so I can check internal data types for all the data types used in python?

Comment: sorry, but I have nothing like that, and I guess in this topic all you need to know: `set`,`dict` - hash table, `list` - array with names (in stack memory) that point to objects (in heap memory), `tuple` - as well as list but we can't change it

Comment: search, insert, del: for `set`, `dict` - O(1) , for `list` - O(n) but for the last item in `list` it's O(1) too

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) you go: "A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects", "The elements of a set must be hashable"

Comment: @sitWolf Thanks a lot. I was searching for the same link.

Comment: @SaurabhVerma glad I could help. I edited this answer for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Given that "a set is a collection which is unordered, unchangeable, and unindexed" and it can hold data of any type, you can guess that a set is a hash table. It is a simplified dictionary.